# How to customize the mail template on Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, email, templates, laravel-5

On Laravel 5.2 I could configure a mail template by putting the following code in the config/auth.php file.

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 1440,
    ],
],
```

This will use my resources/views/auth/emails/password.blade.php file where I can customize the look-and-feel of the email. But it does not work that way Laravel 5.5. How can I customize the email template on Laravel 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

After publishing vendor blade files to your `resources/views/vendor` directory you can edit `email.blade.php` under `resources/views/vendor/notifications` directory:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Or you can completely overrite reset notification by overriting `sendPasswordResetNotification` method in User model:

```
/** 
 * Send the password reset notification. 
 * 
 * @param string $token 
 * @return void 
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token) 
{ 
   $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token)); 
}
```

Comment: I have got an error "Class 'ResetPasswordNotification' not found", I  did place "use ResetPasswordNotification" on top of the User class.

Comment: Are you using correct path for it? It is default notification, you are implementing in this method your form.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with 'using correct path for it'. But I did implement the sendPasswordResetNotification($token) function in my User model. When requesting a password reset link, this method had been called and it tried to create an instance object of new ResetPasswordNotification($token). But it could not find this ResetPasswordNotification class anywhere in my Laravel 5.5 project.

Comment: So you were not looking well. The method `sendPasswordResetNotification` comes from the`CanResetPassword` trait where `ResetPasswordNotification` is an alias for the `ResetPassword` notification.

Answer (score -1):

You publish vendor blade `email.blade.php` file to `resources/views/vendor/notifications`, you use :
`$php artisan vendor:publish`
After you edit file to customize the layout email template.
Continue, you overrite function `sendPasswordResetNotification` in `User` Model 

     `/**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }`

With `ResetPasswordNotification`, you can create `ResetPasswordNotification` in `app\Notifications`. The content is the same as the content of the file `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword`:

`/**
 * Build the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
        ->action('Reset Password', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}`